# php jquery iterate php array in success function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have jquery pop form . It takes one input from the user ,mapping_key , Once the user enters the mapping key   ,i make an ajax call to check if there is a user in the database with such a key. 
This is my call .

**Javascript:**

```
$.ajax({       
    url : base_url+'ns/config/functions.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data : {"mapping_key":mapping_key} ,
    success: function(response) {
            alert(response)                        
    }
});
```

**PHP:**

```
$sql = "select first_name,last_name,user_email,company_name from registered_users where mapping_key = '$mapping_key'";    
$res = mysql_query($sql);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($res);
if($num_rows == 0)
{
    echo $num_rows;
}
else{
    while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
    {
       print_r($result);
    }
}
```

Now i want to loop through the returned array and add those returned values for displaying in another popup form.
Would appreciate any advice or help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your php, echo a json_encoded array:

```
$result = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
   $result[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($result);
```

In your javascript, set the $.ajax dataType property to 'json', then you will be able to loop the returned array:

```
$.ajax({       
    url : base_url+'ns/config/functions.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data : {"mapping_key":mapping_key} ,
    dataType : 'json',
    success: function(response) {
        var i;
        for (i in response) {
          alert(response[i].yourcolumn);
        }                      
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
data : {"mapping_key":mapping_key} ,
```

to

```
data: "mapping_key=" + mapping_key,
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to take the posted `mapping_key`:

```
$mapping_key = $_POST['mapping_key'];

$sql = "select first_name,last_name,user_email,company_name from registered_users
        where mapping_key = '$mapping_key'";
```

or this:

```
$sql = "select first_name,last_name,user_email,company_name from registered_users
        where mapping_key = $_POST['mapping_key']";
```